# C++ Builder Language Font is Broken?

Tags: delphi, fonts, c++builder

I'm using C++ Builder 2010 and for some odd reason today when I opened my project all the non english font(aka korean font) turned into a box and when I try to retype them it still comes out as a box. I was wonder if anyone knows how to fix this

Comment: This sounds like a job for the support people at Borland (or Embarcadero, whatever it is now...).

Comment: That's cause your file format is in ANSI encoding. You should be able to change that by right clicking in editor > FileFormat > etc..

Comment: Thanks for replies, and as for file format encoding, only thing I found was under Option -> Diagram -> Source Code -> Encoding and its set as System Default. And there was bunch of other languages but changing it didn't do anything

Comment: @user3600717, C++Builder 2010 supports unicode, you just have to find the setting. Once you set your file format correctly you will be able to save and open your files with unicode persistence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box indicates that the text encoding is understood, but the font has no glyph for this particular character. You need a font that has support for the characters that you use.

The font used in the IDE's editor windows is specified in your preferences under: [Tools > Options > Editor Options > Display](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/2010/en/Display).

You need to choose a font that supports the language in your code. It sounds like you did that once but somehow the setting has got lost, or perhaps the installed font has been modified.